# FICO Classic (04) Credit Score calculation

Tags: credit-score, fico-score

A mortgage lender has pulled a FICO Classic (04) TransUnion score and it's a 100 points less than any other model I was able to track down (Experian-Vantage, Equifax, etc). Experian tells me the TransUnion FICO 8.0 score is 800, but I can't see the FICO Classic score. The only thing I see that can still be affecting is that I had a payment in collections but was paid off 2 months ago.

The interest rate at that score is way higher than 100 pts more, so I'm trying to get it resolved.

1. Could the payment from 2 months ago still be affecting the FICO Classic (04) score but not any other model?
2. If it does, how long does it take to normalize with the other models?

Any other info on how FICO Classic (04) is calculated would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @littleadv edited

Answer (score 1):

If you have applied for a loan, your creditor must provide you with the scores used and how they obtained them. You can then contact the credit agency for details.

Generally, credit agencies do not disclose how exactly they calculate their scores, but they should tell you what were the most significant factors.

Account in collections is very likely to be a significant factor, and the fact that it was eventually paid off may or may not mitigate how the credit agency sees that. If they value more the accounts *currently* in collection, then paying it off may help, but if they value more accounts *getting* to that state then paying off may not be as helpful in term of recovery (but it will be eventually since all of them value accounts *staying* in collection).

If you reached an agreement with the collection agency that they remove the account altogether and TransUnion tell you that they hadn't - you'll need to work it out with the agency.